# Cocoa app: how to close a window without terminating the app?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am working on a Cocoa app, using Swift. The app opens with a window and the user can open another window using the menu. The problem is that when either window is closed using the red button, the app terminates. I don't want that behavior; I want the app to remain alive. It's not crashing; the AppDelegate's applicationWillTerminate method executes.

The AppDelegate has the method applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed, which returns false, but this method never gets executed.

I am a reasonably competent Swift iOS developer; this is my first real Cocoa app and I suspect this is something simple, but I'm baffled right now. How do I close a window without terminating the app entirely?

Edit: Here are some code snippets:

In the AppDelegate:

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    Log.methodEnter()
    return false
}
```

Also in the AppDelegate, the method to open a window:

```
@IBAction func openVerbSettingsWindow(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    verbSettingsWindowController.showWindow (nil)

}
```

From the windowViewController, the only method that does anything as the window loads and displays:

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    window?.setFrame(NSMakeRect(400.0, 100.0, 950.0, 450.0), display: true)
}
```

I'm hopeful this helps!

Comment: It depends on whether you are using NSViewController, NSWindowController or just AppDelegate with a Xib file.

Comment: I just made a default Cocoa application in Xcode, and ran it, and when I close the window, it doesn't quit -- so it sounds like something you're doing.  What's your program?  Can we see the source code?

Comment: When I started writing this app, it worked, but when I added the second window, the terminating behavior started. So it must have something to do with that second window, but I sure don't know what it is! In response to El Tomato, the second window is an NSWindow, it's controlled by an NSWindowController subclass, and it uses an .XIB file.

Comment: Where is your AppDelegate created? Is it in the MainMenu interface file? Is it actually hooked up as the app’s delegate in there, if so? If not, where do you set it as the delegate?

Comment: The AppDelegate is in theMainMenu interface file and is hooked to the application delegate there also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a little embarrassed at the answer to this question; it has nothing to do with Cocoa or my code.

I have an app called RedQuits that configures OS X to close an app when that app's last window closes, rather than leaving the app running with no windows (OS X default behavior). When I got rid of RedQuits and re-booted so that OS X would return to its default behavior, the problem went away. For some reason, RedQuits causes my Cocoa app to quit when *any* application window closes. Interestingly, I found this because it causes the same behavior in Xcode: close one project window and Xcode shut down.